# Recovery Point Objective(RPO) vs Recovery Time Objective (RTO)

Tags: sql-server

What is the main differences between Recovery Point Objective(RPO) and Recovery Time Objective (RTO) in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

**Recovery Point Objective(RPO) :**
In simple term means how much data loss is acceptable..This dictates the frequency you take backups

**Recovery Time Objective (RTO):**
How much downtime is acceptable

These two terms are also closely related in dictating your disaster recovery plans and also the costs that will incur ..

Below is a chart from [Brentozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/)

[image]

References:
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-6-of-30-backups-understanding-rto-and-rpo/

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/

Comment: Just to provide a little context for RTO, another way to say it is: "if something happened that necessitated a restore, how long would it take you to bring your data into a state that is usable?"